# Swift dictionary put [UInt8] as a value does not work

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uint

I create a dictionary in Swift:

```
var type:String
var content:[UInt8]
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue(type, forKey: "type")
dict.setValue(content, forKey: "content")
```

I get an error: `Cannot convert value of type [UInt8] to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`, but if I change the content type as `[UInt]`, it will work fine. Why?

In fact, I want to define a byte array as in Java, so I want to use `[UInt8]`, anyone could help me?

Comment: @Russell Yes, already tried and got failed.

Comment: You are creating an NSDictionary, which cannot store arrays of instrinsic types, it can only store NSArrays and NSArrays can only store object types, so you will need to store an array of NSNumbers and box the UInt8 into an NSNumber before storing it in the array or use a native Swift dictionary which can store an array of UInt8

Comment: Int/UInt (and Float/Double) are automatically bridged to NSNumber, but the fixed-size integer types like UInt8 are not.

Comment: @Paulw I tried this with native swift dictinary, but still failed.             var dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
            dict["type"] = type
            dict["content"] = content

Comment: @Martin But I need a UInt8 array, so how to handle this? I  am a ios newbie.

Comment: If you need a UInt8 array then you will need to box/unbox the NSNumbers yourself - with `NSNumber(unsignedChar:)` and `content[0].unsignedCharValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Swift native types

```
var dict: Dictionary<String,Array<UInt8>> = [:]
dict["first"]=[1,2,3]
print(dict) // ["first": [1, 2, 3]]
```

i recommend you to use native Swift type as much as you can ... Please, see Martins's notes to you question, it is very useful!

if the case is you want to store there any value, just define you dictionary as the proper type

```
var dict: Dictionary<String,Array<Any>> = [:]
dict["first"]=[1,2,3]
class C {
}
dict["second"] = ["alfa", Int(1), UInt(1), C()]
print(dict) // ["first": [1, 2, 3], "second": ["alfa", 1, 1, C]]
```

to see, that the type of the value is still well known, you can check it

```
dict["second"]?.forEach({ (element) -> () in
    print(element, element.dynamicType)
})

/*
alfa String
1 Int
1 UInt
C C
*/
```

if you want to store Any value, you are free to do it ...

```
var type:String = "test"
var content:[UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
var dict: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]
dict["type"] = type
dict["content"] = content
dict.forEach { (element) -> () in // ["content": [1, 2, 3, 4], "type": "test"]
    print("key:", element.0, "value:", element.1, "with type:", element.1.dynamicType)
    /*
    key: content value: [1, 2, 3, 4] with type: Array<UInt8>
    key: type value: test with type: String
    */
}
```

Comment: Of course what you did is right, but for your dictionary can only put UInt8 array as value, it can not put other types(String,Int etc.). I need a dictionary that can put string value, int value and UInt8 array value.

Comment: it is up to you, what do you want to store in your dictionary ... see my update

Comment: what I want like this:             var type:String = "test"
            var content:[UInt8] = [1,2,3,4]
            var dict: Dictionary<String,Array<Any>> = [:]
            dict["type"] = type
            dict["content"] = content

Comment: what you did is any type in the Array, I want multiple types of the dictionary value

Comment: so, do you want to store Any value in you dictionary? see my 'final' example :-)

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. But unfortunately this Generic constraint of Dictionary is not suitable for SwiftyJSON: JSON(dict). But I think it is another question ^_^. Thanks a lot.